# Category theory on Kahler geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, complex-geometry

I try to understand the Grothendieck philosophy, I understand that a mathematical object induces naturally a Functor (the Hom Functor) and the information about this object is encrypted in its category. In the Mochizuki´s paper [Categorical Representation of Local Noetherian Log Schemes](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/Categorical%20Representation%20of%20Locally%20Noetherian%20Log%20Schemes.pdf), Mochizuki characterizes an algebraic variety using the subcategory of the finite type morphisms in the comma category. Specifically he has shown that the set of morphisms between two varieties is naturally isomorphic to the set of morphisms in his induced categories.

My intuition says that using the Yoneda's lemma, a similar characterization can be made. My question is if there are similar results to the Mochizuki's paper in other categories, for example Kahler manifolds.

Comment: I think the right place to make the same question is probably MOF and not here. The same people that can give you an answer here are there as well, plus some others who might know. Your question seems to be interesting though.